# Image rescale (downsize) with Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have an array of graphs, that are 2000x1000 pixels pngs. When I put them into a silverlight Image that auto-sized with the browser window, `DisplayImage.Source = new BitmapImage(GetHeatmapURL());` they images look distorted and for some browser sizes much worse than for some others.

I want to fiddle with some setting that would improve the quality of this downsampling, is this possible? Am I doing something wrong? My first approach was to put the Image into a Viewbox. That looked even worse. Googling gives virtually nothing useful...

Any help much appreciated.

PS. I'm working with Silverlight 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check out the [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) project on CodePlex which gives you a Resize() extension method for the Silverlight WritableBitmap class where you can use either Bilinear or Nearest Neighbor interpolation. Resizing with the Bilinear interpolation might give you something that looks better than the ViewBox resizing, but you would have to test it out.

```
var resized = writeableBmp.Resize(200, 300, WriteableBitmapExtensions.Interpolation.Bilinear);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

When making use of the `Viewbox` you need to make sure to set `Stretch` to `Uniform` to respect the original height/width ratio.

In regards to the rendering of the image at the given aspect ratio and size; that is contingent on the framework.

Comment: Yes, I understand that I need to keep the aspect ratio. I just want some kind of different downsampling algorithm. It might be more computationally expensive than the current one, as long as it's pretty then I'm happy.

Comment: @Gleno Have you attempted to scale the image down before bringing it into SL; to see how it looks scaled up? Would be curious if you have same issues...